# jQuery + x-editable: dynamic url ajax?

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I am using [x-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) to edit content. In the official doc it says "Open your page and click on element. Enter new value and submit form. It will send ajax request with new value to `/post`".

This is what I would like to do, however my url is dynamic. I want to know how can I generate a dynanmic url?

Here's the UI showing content and editable enable:

[image]

[image]

Right now when I just enter `http://localhost:5055/update/department?id=55&name=yoo` in my browser, the corresponding content on my UI will be update. The problem is each data has a different id and different name, so the url will be dynamic `/update/department?id=dynamicID&name=newvalue`

How can I generate a dynamica url using x-editable?

Currently I add `data-url="/update/department?id=${department.optString("departmentId")}&name="` inside my `<a>`, but having trouble figure out how to set `name=` .

In my js file, I tried:

```
$('.to-be-edited').editable({
    toggle: 'manual',
    //submit data without pk please set send option to "always".
    //send: 'always',
    url: '$(this).data("url") + newValue',
    success: function(res, newValue) {
      console.log(newValue)
    }

  })
```

And I got an error: 
`POST http://localhost:8000/update/department?id=55&name= 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

code to render table

```
        <c:if test="${departments.length() > 0}">
          <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${departments.length()-1}">
          <c:set var="department" value="${departments.getJSONObject(i)}"/>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="#"
                class="to-be-edited department-name" data-type="text"
                data-pk="${department.optString("departmentId")}" 
                id="${department.optString("departmentId")}" 
                data-url="/update/department?id=${department.optString("departmentId")}&name=">${department.optString("departmentName")}</a><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw pencil-edit-name" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
              <td> <a href="#" class="edit-name">Edit Name</a> </td>
            </tr>
          </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.
First, I added `object-type="something"` to the `<a>` tag. This in an important attribute because other page will use the same function, so the `url` must be dynamic. For example, in department page:

```
<a href="#"
   class="to-be-edited department-name" data-type="text"
   data-pk="${department.optString("departmentId")}" 
   id="${department.optString("departmentId")}"
   object-type="department"
>
```

in vendor page:

```
<a href="#"
   class="to-be-edited vendor-name" data-type="text"
   data-pk="$${vendor.optString("vendorId")}" 
   id="$${vendor.optString("vendorId")}"
   object-type="vendor"
>
```

Then, in my js, I create a success function, generate the url, then write the ajax inside the success function

```
$('.to-be-edited').editable({
    toggle: 'manual',
    success: function(something, data) {
      //generate dynamic url for ajax
      let url = "/update/" + $(this).attr('object-type') + "?id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&name=" + data;
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        //http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings
        //communication successful with server, check the status
        success: function ajaxSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          let json = JSON.parse(data);
          if (json["status"] === "success") {
            //content will update on server side
            console.log(data);
          } else {
            alert('Unable to update, try again later. ' + json["reason"]);
            return;
          }
        },
        //unable to communicate with server
        error: function communicationError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('Unable to update, try later. ' + errorThrown);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```